# Agendar envio de email após consultar status de transação

Tags: php, aplicação-web, envio-de-email

Estou criando um página que possui um modulo de pagamento, mas quando um usuário faz um pagamento logo após a transação ser aprovada ele recebe um email avisando o mesmo que sua transação foi aceita ou não, mas em alguns casos a transação leva um tempo para ser processada, como faço para que o sistema fique consultando o status do pagamento e envie um email ao usuário mesmo ele não estando na página.

Comment: Você pode criar uma tabela registrando os usuários cujo pagamento está como pendente, e então criar um script para percorrer essa tabela a cada X time, agendando a tarefa no Cronjob

Comment: @LeoLetto pesquisei sobre o Cron Jobs e fiquei com uma dúvida, este recurso é somente disponível para o Windows ou posso usar em servidores Linux?

Comment: Na verdade ele é para Linux '-', você ta editando via cPanel ou manualmente no linux?

Comment: @LeoLetto Na verdade eu não tenho acesso ao painel dessa hospedagem, isso só pode ser feito através do painel ou é possível fazer através de código php?

Comment: Para agendar tarefas você precisa de acesso ao painel, ou a linha de comando do Linux

Comment: @LeoLetto ficou claro, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Se não se importar, existem alguns serviços que fazer POST programadamente para uma página especificada, como você não tem acesso painel, é melhor usar um serviço de 3º

Comment: Da uma olhada, talvez atenda suas necessidade https://uptimerobot.com/

Comment: Você pode montar um webservice e chamar ele pra execução a cada 5 minutos, porém, sobrecarregaria o servidor (penso eu), o certo mesmo seria a execução pelo cron do Cpanel ou do SRV Linux... mas a ideia é justamente essa, em partes, o include resolveria o problema.